# Why does the value of the parameter to this F# function seem to change to 0?

Tags: parameters, f#, matching

I'm trying to write a recursive function for building a specialized card deck. The first parameter, numOfCards is supposed to be the number of cards in the deck. The sourceDeck is a list of possible cards that can be used to build the deck and the currentDeck is my accumulator, which results in the final list of cards.

However, the problem I have is that when I send in a number value for numOfCards it gets set to 0 in the match statement. Or at least that's how it looks. I tried stepping through with the debugger, and when I enter the function, the value is correct. As soon as I start executing the match, however, it suddenly becomes 0, both if I hover over the value in the match and over the value in the parameters (which is at least consistent).

As such, the match triggers on 0 and just returns the empty currentDeck, rather than iterating.

Any tips on this one? Probably something simple, but I'm stumped. :)

```
let rec buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck : List<Card>, currentDeck : List<Card>) =
  match currentDeck.Length with
    | numOfCards  -> currentDeck
    | _           -> buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck, newCard(sourceDeck)::currentDeck)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to handle a case when `currentDeck.Length` *equals* `numOfCards` then you need to write:

```
let rec buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck : List<Card>, currentDeck : List<Card>) =
  match currentDeck.Length with
  | n when n = numOfCards -> currentDeck
  | _ -> buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck, newCard(sourceDeck)::currentDeck)
```

The problem is that when you write a clause `| numOfCards -> (...)`, the pattern matching binds the value of `currentDeck.Length` to the symbol `numOfCards` (and the newly defined `numOfCards` value hides the previous value of the same name - that is, the value you got as a parameter).

The pattern matching I wrote above binds `currentDeck.Length` to a *new* symbol `n` and then checks that `n = numOfCards` (referring to the `numOfCards` passed as an argument).

So, pattern matching is not really the best tool for checking equality - and your code could be probably more easily written using normal `if`:

```
let rec buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck : List<Card>, currentDeck : List<Card>) =
  if currentDeck.Length = numOfCards then currentDeck
  else buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck, newCard(sourceDeck)::currentDeck)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the example on how to fix it. Or both examples, I should say. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `numOfCards` in the `match` expression is not the same as the one in the parameters:  it's a new variable that's *shadowing* the old one.  Since it's an unbounded variable pattern, it will match anything at all and bind itself to that thing.  Thus, the second (wildcard) pattern is never reached, because the first one never fails.

Comment: Aha! Would almost expect the debugger to show different values in the two values then, but guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand pattern matching in F# you should use

```
let rec buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck : List<Card>, currentDeck : List<Card>) =
  match currentDeck.Length with
  | n when n = numOfCards -> currentDeck
  | _ -> buildDungeon (numOfCards, sourceDeck, newCard(sourceDeck)::currentDeck)
```

By specifying the pattern sort of create new variables (n in this example). You are not using the already defined.